# AWS SDK in Visual Studio always exits with a message of saying that it didn't raise a CoreCLR started event

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

After creating a sample Amazon SDK application in Visual Studio 2022, like a Lambda with a SQS queue, I get the following error when I launch using the Mock Lambda Test Tool:

> The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event.
> Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This
> may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core. The
> program '[10860] dotnet-lambda-test-tool-6.0.exe' has exited with code
> 2147516570 (0x8000809a).

I'm using .net 6.
I've done a clean and rebuild.
I've made sure that Visual Studio has the latest updates and updated the AWS Toolkit to the latest version.

Anyone know a solution? I used to be able to do this without error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599978/cannot-start-lambda-with-mock-lambda-test-tool

Comment: @HansPassant - That helped solve my problem ... thank you!